# Aligning the right hand side of multiline equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

I would like to align the RHS of the multiline equations and assign equation number for whole as one.

```
\begin{multline*}
\frac{\partial P(y_{i}\succ0)} {\partial z_{ij}}=\tfrac {a(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}a^{2}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)^{2}}\\
\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau \left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\right)\gamma_{1j}+\tfrac {b(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}b^{2j}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}\\
\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
=\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
=\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}-\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{multline*}
```

How do I do that?. I couldn't get it using `align`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production (egreg does not like this)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial P(y_{i}\succ0)} {\partial z_{ij}}
&=
\!
\begin{multlined}[t][10cm]
\tfrac{a(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}a^{2}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)^{2}}
\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}
-a\tau \left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\right)
\gamma_{1j}\\
+\tfrac {b(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}b^{2j}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}\\
\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{multlined}\\
&=
\!
\begin{multlined}[t][10cm]
\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{multlined}\\
&=
\!
\begin{multlined}[t][10cm]
\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}-\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{multlined}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[For better resolution click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V29nC.png)

Comment: primes are really bad.  as mentioned by others, either use `^{\prime}` or an apostrophe.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand your intentions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{\partial P(y_{i}\succ0)} {\partial z_{ij}}&=\tfrac {a(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}a^{2}(1\tau^{2})^{2}\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)^{2}}\times\\
  &\qquad\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau \left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
  &\qquad{}+\tfrac {b(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}b^{2j}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}\\
  &\qquad\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
  &=\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
  &\qquad{}+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
  &=\phi\left(z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-\tau z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
  &\qquad{}+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{z_{1i}\prime\gamma_{1j}-\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}\prime\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some changes are still needed. In particular, `\prime`'s look very strange.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tentative solution that uses the `split` environment inside an `equation` environment to ensure that the entire construct is assigned just one "number".

Note that I've used `\qquad` to indent terms multiplicatively linked to the preceding material, and `\quad` for terms linked additively to the preceding material. I've also replaced various `\prime` statements with `'`; if you prefer `\prime`, I believe it should be typeset in superscript position, and thus should be entered as `^{\prime}`. Finally, in the lines following the third equal sign, I've replaced the `\left(` and `\right)` statements encasing the big `\Phi` terms with `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` as the parentheses otherwise completely dominate, visually speaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial P(y_{i}\succ0)} {\partial z_{ij}}
&=\tfrac {a(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} 
e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}a^{2}(1-\tau^{2})^{2} \left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)^{2}}\\
&\qquad\times\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau \left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)\right)\gamma_{1j}\\ 
&\quad+\tfrac {b(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} 
e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}b^{2j}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}\\
&\qquad \times \Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)- b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
&=\phi\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)\gamma_{1j}\\
&\quad+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
&=\phi\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}\right)
\Phi\biggl(\tfrac{\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-\tau z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\biggr)\gamma_{1j}\\
&\quad+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)
\Phi\biggl(\tfrac{z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}-\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\biggr)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum: Assuming your text block is sufficiently wide, the whole equation construct could be typeset in four lines instead of eight; however, I don't think the intelligibility increases from such an attempt to economize on vertical space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial P(y_{i}\succ0)} {\partial z_{ij}}
&=\tfrac {a(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} 
e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}a^{2}(1-\tau^{2})^{2} \left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)^{2}}
\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau \left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)\right)\gamma_{1j}\\ 
&\quad+\tfrac {b(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}{(2 \pi)^{1/2}} 
e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}b^{2j}(1-\tau^{2})^{2}\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}
\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)- b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
&=\phi\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}\right)\Phi\left(b\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-a\tau z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)\gamma_{1j}
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(a\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}\right)-b\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}\right)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}\\
&=\phi\left(z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}\right)
\Phi\biggl(\tfrac{\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}-\tau z_{1i}'\gamma_{1}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\biggr)\gamma_{1j}
+\phi\left(\tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2}}{\sigma}\right)
\Phi\biggl(\tfrac{z_{1i}'\gamma_{1j}-\tau \tfrac{z_{2i}'\gamma_{2j}}{\sigma}}{(1-\tau^{2})^{1/2}}\biggr)\tfrac{\gamma_{2j}}{\tau}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```